# The border width I specified didn't get applied to the targeted element

Tags: html, css

So I'm in midst of trying to create a 3x3 board using css, when I notice this problem. I've set `border: solid 0.1px` to my `.tile` elements, in the hope that they will fit into a parent element, the width of which I've set to 360.6 px. However, upon inspecting the elements, I notice that the border for each side of `.tile` is 0.8 px. No matter how much I delete and re-add the attribute, the width of the border remain 0.8 px. As of now, I've decided to adjust the width & height of `.board` as a stopgap measure. I would be grateful if somebody tell me why the width of my border is set at 0.8, not 0.1 px.

Here is my code:

```css
.board{
    display: flex;
    width: 364.8px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 184.8px;
}

.tile{
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    border: dotted 0.1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="board">
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```